# Given an array of ints length 3, figure out which is larger, the first or last element in the array, and set all the other elements to be that value

Tags: python

Given an array of ints length 3, figure out which is larger, the first or last element in the array, and set all the other elements to be that value. Return the changed array

```
    def max_end3(nums):
       if nums[0:] > nums[:-1]:
       # this is where I am lost
    return print(nums)
       elif nums[:-1] > nums[0:]:
       # this is where I am lost
    return print(nums)  

    max_end3([1, 2, 3])
    max_end3([11, 5, 9])
    max_end3([2, 11, 3])
```

I am missing something and I cant seem to remember it. there is a +1 somewhere that allows me to iterate through each element and modify them as it goes. I cannot seem to remember how to assign the larger value to every item in the list.
Here is a link to the problem   https://codingbat.com/prob/p135290

I appreciate any assistance.
Thank You.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is your **question**? What went wrong when you tried the code, or what are you confused about? When you say that you "are lost", what is it that you're trying to "find" and can't? What do you mean by "a +1"?

Comment: I cannot remember how to assign the larger value and then apply it to every item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the maximum value using in-built `max` and form a list of the maximum values:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    m = max(nums[0], nums[-1])
    print([m for _ in nums])
```

Comment: would you please explain the for _ in portion of your code.  I have not see it before. and thank you it worked.

Comment: @Mr.Mac, They are throwaway variables., Just for the purpose of iteration and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a list comprehension to change all the values, it would be something like

```
list = [value = list[:0] for value in list]
```

also the return statements aren't indented

Comment: Your current answer is much more a _comment_ than it is _an answer_. When you give an answer then it needs to answer the question. Commenting will be available to you after you gained 50 reputation points. In any case, refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not even close to working. It's not even valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
def max_end3(nums):
  return 3 * [max(nums[0], nums[-1])]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).